# How to find all maximal sets $S_i$ of a given array $T$ such that every element of $S_i$ is greater than or equal to the cardinality of $S_i$

Tags: algorithms

Lately, I asked [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66048/how-to-find-the-maximal-set-of-elements-s-of-an-array-such-that-every-element) to find the maximal set of elements $S$ of a given array $T$ such that every element of $S$ is greater than or equal to the cardinality of $S$.

My question is now different. How to find ***all*** maximal sets $S_i$ of a given array $T$ such that every element of $S_i$ is greater than or equal to the cardinality of $S_i$.

For example, if $T=[9, 8, 2, 2, 1]$, then all maximal sets that satisfy the condition are $S_1=[9, 8]$, $S_2=[9, 2]$, $S_3=[9, 2]$, $S_4=[8, 2]$, $S_5=[8, 2]$ and $S_6=[2, 2]$.

My recursive solution or the solutions given in the previous question do not generate ***all*** maximal sets.

Is there any efficient algorithm that finds ***all*** maximal sets of such problem?

I think one way to solve the problem is to find *a* maximal set $S$ and return its size $|S|$--using any algorithm from [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66048/how-to-find-the-maximal-set-of-elements-s-of-an-array-such-that-every-element). Then, generate all combinations $\displaystyle\binom{|T|}{|S|}$ and find which one of these combinations satisfies the condition. But can we do better?

Comment: Obviously, you can drop 1 from T, once you know that |S|=2. Other than that (and some duplicate handling), there is nothing to improve. There really are that many maximal sets.

Comment: What do you mean by *maximal* set? Maximum size, or inclusion-maximal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that by *maximal sets* you mean sets of maximal size (rather than sets which are inclusion-maximal), then there is a very simple algorithm. First, find the maximal size $s$. Second, filter out all elements smaller than $s$. Third, output all subsets of size $s$ of the remaining elements.

Comment: Good. I think this works fine. Thanks.